# Scan folder and list only image files with vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to make the script to scan a folder and list only image files such as jpg, png, gif.
This is the code

```
Dim fso, ObjFolder, ObjOutFile, ObjFiles, ObjFile, outputFile, inputFileList
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8, CreateIfNeeded = true

inputFileList = "list.txt"
outputFile = "C:\Users\Susan\Documents\iMacros\Macros\WindowsFiles.txt"
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile = fso.OpenTextFile(inputFileList, ForReading)

Do Until objTextFile.AtEndOfStream
 sFolderName = objTextFile.Readline
 wscript.Echo "writing contents of " & sFolderName
 writefilenames(sFolderName)
Loop

function writefilenames(sFolderName)
  Set ObjFolder = fso.GetFolder(sFolderName)

  If fso.FileExists(outputFile) Then
    Set ObjOutFile = fso.OpenTextFile(outputFile, ForAppending)
  Else
    Set ObjOutFile = fso.OpenTextFile(outputFile, ForWriting, CreateIfNeeded)
  End If

  Set ObjFiles = ObjFolder.Files

  For Each ObjFile In ObjFiles
    ObjOutFile.WriteLine(ObjFile.Path)
  Next

  ObjOutFile.Close
end function
```

Can anyone give me the proper code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Execute the command `ObjOutFile.WriteLine(ObjFile.Path)` only when `ObjFile` has a matching extension.

```
Set extensions = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
extensions.CompareMode = 1 ' make lookups case-insensitive
extensions.Add "jpg", True
extensions.Add "png", True
extensions.Add "gif", True

'...

For Each ObjFile In ObjFiles
  If extensions.Exists(fso.GetExtensionName(ObjFile)) Then
    ObjOutFile.WriteLine(ObjFile.Path)
  End If
Next
```

And please don't [broadcast](http://www.visualbasicscript.com/fb.ashx?m=99277) your questions. It's not very polite towards the people you're asking for help.